# Your Account is pending - iTunes Sales & Trends

Tags: ios, itunes

i get the following error when i try to connect Sales & Trends..

Any idea what this means?

[image]

Comment: Have you signed all the contracts?

Comment: Why don't you just contact them?

Comment: It happened to me after switching between Apple accounts. Clearing all the Apple related cookies've helped.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 12):

After 2 hours it worked automatically.

I own the account over a year and have received several payments, so all contracts are correctly configured.

In the developer forum I've read that others had the same problem.

Comment: Same here, after a bit (not even an hour) it went away. I also happened to have one of the contracts pending approval, but we didn't do anything about it before the account started working.

Answer (score 2):

Go to "Contracts, Tax, and Banking" and setup your bank and tax related info. Look likes you did not request a contract information for paid apps. Once you done with it you will be able to access "Sales and Trends".

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

It also happens during

> "System maintenance in progress..."

Just go to "Agreements, Tax and Banking" section and you might see this message there. Just give them a min or two ;-)